# Space among nested tabs

Tags: html, css

Anyone can explain me why in the nested tabs I have it inside the second tab (the one named "Letture") there is a space on the right of the tab while in the first one it isn't?

The CSS code for both tabs is the same, I don't see it why they behave differently

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
  
  $('ul.tabs li').each(function () {
   var nimg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
   $(this).find('img').attr('src', nimg.replace('_r', '_g'));
  });
  
  var img = $(this).find( 'img' ).attr('src');
  $(this).find( 'img' ).attr('src', img.replace('_g', '_r'));
  
 });
$("ul.subtabs li").click(function(){
   var tab_id = $(this).attr("data-tab");

   $("ul.subtabs li").removeClass("current");
   $(".subtab-content").removeClass("current");

   $(this).addClass("current");
   $("#"+tab_id).addClass("current");
   
   $("ul.subtabs li").each(function () {
    var nimg = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", nimg.replace("_r", "_g"));
   });
   
   var img = $(this).find( "img" ).attr("src");
   $(this).find( "img" ).attr("src", img.replace("_g", "_r"));
  });
```

```css
ul.tabs, ul.subtabs{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li, ul.subtabs li{
 line-height: 24px;
 background: #ededed;
 color: #777;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font: 16pt arial,verdana !important;
 border: 1px solid rgb(164, 162, 162);
 border-right: medium none;
}

ul.tabs li.current, ul.subtabs li.current{
 background: none;
 color: rgb(227,32,46);
 border-bottom: 0;
 border-top: 3px solid rgb(227,32,46);
 padding-top: 8px;
}

.tab-content, .subtab-content {
 display: none;
 padding-top: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current, .subtab-content.current {
 display: inherit;
}

ul.tabs > li > img, ul.subtabs > li > img {
 margin-right: 5px;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
}

.tabLast {
 border-right: 1px solid rgb(164, 162, 162) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
   <li data-tab="tab-1" class="tab-link"><img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png"> Amministratore</li><li data-tab="tab-2" class="tab-link current"><img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_r.png"> Letture</li><li data-tab="tab-3" class="tab-link"><img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png"> Unità immobiliari</li><li data-tab="tab-5" class="tab-link tabLast"><img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png"> Riparti</li></ul>
<div data-loaded="1" class="tab-content" id="tab-1"><div class="mb20">&nbsp;</div><h3>Amministratore</h3></div>
<div data-loaded="1" class="tab-content current" id="tab-2"><ul class="subtabs">
    <li data-tab="tab-af" class="tab-link"><img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png"> Acqua fredda</li>
 <li data-tab="tab-ac" class="tab-link"><img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png"> Acqua calda</li>
    <li data-tab="tab-ca" class="tab-link tabLast current"><img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_r.png"> Calore</li>
  </ul><div id="tab-af" class="subtab-content" data-loaded="1">Freddo!</div>
 <div id="tab-ac" class="subtab-content" data-loaded="1">Caldo!</div>
 <div id="tab-ca" class="subtab-content current" data-loaded="1">Calore!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's additional whitespace after the Acqua fredda li elem. Remove this and the problem vanishes. I.e if the markup is Acqua fredda</li><li> the problem is gone. The below answer says the same thing.

Comment: Yes! I see it now, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because they are displayed as `inline-block` which are an inline element, and therefore creates a gap, so one way to solve this is set `font-size:0` to parent `ul`.

See more info [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');

  $('ul.tabs li').each(function() {
    var nimg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', nimg.replace('_r', '_g'));
  });

  var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  $(this).find('img').attr('src', img.replace('_g', '_r'));

});
$("ul.subtabs li").click(function() {
  var tab_id = $(this).attr("data-tab");

  $("ul.subtabs li").removeClass("current");
  $(".subtab-content").removeClass("current");

  $(this).addClass("current");
  $("#" + tab_id).addClass("current");

  $("ul.subtabs li").each(function() {
    var nimg = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", nimg.replace("_r", "_g"));
  });

  var img = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", img.replace("_g", "_r"));
});
```

```css
ul.tabs,
ul.subtabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size:0
}
ul.tabs li,
ul.subtabs li {
  line-height: 24px;
  background: #ededed;
  color: #777;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 16pt arial, verdana !important;
  border: 1px solid rgb(164, 162, 162);
  border-right: medium none;
}
ul.tabs li.current,
ul.subtabs li.current {
  background: none;
  color: rgb(227, 32, 46);
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(227, 32, 46);
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.tab-content,
.subtab-content {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current,
.subtab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
ul.tabs > li > img,
ul.subtabs > li > img {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
.tabLast {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(164, 162, 162) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li data-tab="tab-1" class="tab-link">
    <img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png">Amministratore</li>
  <li data-tab="tab-2" class="tab-link current">
    <img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_r.png">Letture</li>
  <li data-tab="tab-3" class="tab-link">
    <img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png">Unità immobiliari</li>
  <li data-tab="tab-5" class="tab-link tabLast">
    <img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png">Riparti</li>
</ul>
<div data-loaded="1" class="tab-content" id="tab-1">
  <div class="mb20">&nbsp;</div>
  <h3>Amministratore</h3>
</div>
<div data-loaded="1" class="tab-content current" id="tab-2">
  <ul class="subtabs">
    <li data-tab="tab-af" class="tab-link">
      <img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png">Acqua fredda</li>
    <li data-tab="tab-ac" class="tab-link">
      <img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png">Acqua calda</li>
    <li data-tab="tab-ca" class="tab-link tabLast current">
      <img style="float:left;" src="http://www.fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_r.png">Calore</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-af" class="subtab-content" data-loaded="1">Freddo!</div>
  <div id="tab-ac" class="subtab-content" data-loaded="1">Caldo!</div>
  <div id="tab-ca" class="subtab-content current" data-loaded="1">Calore!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that your solution works. Still i don't understand why, being `inline-block` both main tabs and sub tabs, the problem appear only on the sub tabs and not on the main ones.

Comment: in my snippet If I remove `font-size:0` both tabs  have gaps, because I tidy  up the code.

Comment: yes, i've checked and it's true. But in my snippet no: the gaps there's only in the nest tabs. I don't see other differencies between your snippet and mine

Comment: @TizianoMischi I just edited my comment, because I tidy my code the `<li></li><li></li>`, became `<li>    </li>   <li>    </li>`, and that's where the `font-size:0` come in in handy, so you can have your code very beautiful

Comment: Yes, now I see. The `font-size:0` in this case is unimportant. Thanks!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer to be honest. Covers a lot of ground...

Comment: @DavidWilkinson thanks, but OP will accept what OP thinks what is best for him/her. (Even tho I agree that my answer covers a lot more ground than the other)

Comment: Thanks dippas, after having read the article you linked, indeed i've changed my mind and accepted yours as the answer because is more complete that the one of @kreven. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2):

It is know issue. Happens because of new lines after `li` elements with `inline-block` display option.
The firs tabs have no spaces because HTML is

```
<ul>
 <li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

The second tabs have spaces because:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's one of the answers to fight `inline-block` gap, as shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), and this is happening because your code is a mess. if you tidy up this won't be the answer anymore

Comment: @dippas you're right that's because i haven't written this code in html, i've just copied&pasted the result of a php script that created the html, that's why the html isn't tidy. But the php script is cleaner.